# laravel 5.4 count() function error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using **laravel 5.4**, there is an error in the code below,
but there is no error when using **laravel 5.3**,
why is it?

**controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $user=\Auth::user();
    $articles=$user->articles;

    return view('index',  compact('user','articles'));
}
```

**view:**

```
{{ $articles->count() }}
```

**error:**

```
Call to a member function count() on null
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.4 you should try:

```
{{ count($articles) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `count($articles)`. `->count()` on a null value produces indeed an error.